# Header and footer in center of page

Tags: css

Can anyone append this code to make header and footer in center eg. left and right margin should be same

```css
.newheader
{
    background:#000;
    height:30px;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
}
.newfooter
{
    background:#000;
    bottom:0;
    height:30px;
    left:0;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: If your width is 100% it stretches all the way across the screen. There *is* no margin.

Comment: and if you are using fixed width than try `margin: auto;`

Comment: Technically his header and footers are centered.

Comment: What's with all the downvoting? I thought this was the summer of love?

Comment: @NikolaK. that's what I told him if header and footer are having width say 800px; than he can use margin: auto; may be he's using 100% and he wants to do something like what I suggested

Comment: .newheader
{
background:#000;
 height:30px;
  left:5%;
   position:fixed;
    width:90%;
  top:0;
  
}

Comment: @Mr.Alien I saw that after posted the comment and deleted. Didn't read carefully. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to position elements in the middle of a page is to define a width smaller than the full width and then set it's margin with auto.

e.g

```css
.newheader {
    width:960px; /* less than 100% since 100% has no margin */
    margin : 0 auto /* top and bottom margin = 0 left and right auto*/
}
```

**Update with examples**

Here a link to an example based on the page. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/VakYX/2/)

Fullscreen version [link](http://jsfiddle.net/VakYX/2/)

Comment: i want like this http://www.stern.nyu.edu/,if you resized the browser all contemts i-e header,footer will move in center

Comment: Check my linked examples

Answer (score 0):

Do you just mean to contents in the header and footer centered - like the text?

```css
.newheader                /* remove width: 100% */
{
    text-align: center;   /* this line */
    background:#000;
    height:30px;
    left:0;          /* this is setting the div all the way to the left */
    position:fixed;             
    top:0;
}
```

Try this

```css
.newheader
{
    background:#000;
    height:30px;    
    position:relative;       
}

.header_container
{
    top: 0px
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Put the header in the container.

Comment: no whole header div in center,same by giving left 50px and so,i tried but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add `text-align:center;` to both newHeader and newFooter. Since you are already at 100% width there will be no side margins as it will take up 100% of the browser.

```html
<style type="text/css">
.newheader {
    background:#FFF;
    top:0;
    height:30px;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.newfooter {
    background:#CCC;
    bottom:0;
    height:30px;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>

<div class='newHeader'>
   Test Header
</div>
<div>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
<div class='newFooter'>
   Test Footer
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per comment on the original post: `.newheader { background:#000; height:30px; left:5%; position:fixed; width:90%; top:0; }` is the attempt the poster made.

If you have a width of 90%, you can center this header like so:

```
.newheader {
    /*remove position: fixed; left: 5%; top: 0; */
    width:90%;
    margin: 0 auto; /* this centers it */
    height: 30px;
    background: #000;
}
```

Here is a sample [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yk2MG/) of the result.